# prevent body scrolling when sidenav is selected

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm looking for a way to prevent `body` from scrolling when `sidenav` is shown. I've created an overlay `div` and controlled it using jQuery.

**HTML/CSS:**

```
<div id="_blocker"></div>


<style>
#_blocker
{
/* Do not display it on entry */
 display: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index:998;
 /* make it cover the whole screen */
 position: fixed;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background :rgb(0,0,0);
 opacity: 0;
 transition-delay: 2s;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;}
 </style>
```

**JQuery:**

```
function func(){
  $("#sidebar_container").css({"transform": "translate3d(-102%, 0px, 0px)"});
  $('#_blocker').css({'display':'none',"opacity":"0"});
}
$('.menu_btn').on('click',function(){
  $('#sidebar_container').css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});
  $('#_blocker').css({'display':'block',"opacity":"0.4"});
});
$('#_blocker').on('click',function(){
  func();
});
```

The overlay is hiding the `body` and the `sidenav` is scrolling, the **problem** is that the `body` is scrolling too. I've searched and tried everything but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable vertical scrolling on any element use:

```
yourSelector {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

To re-enable it, use `overflow-y: auto;`.

In your case, `yourSelector` is `body`. You have two options:

**a) the clean way: use a class**

add

```
body.noScroll {overflow-y:hidden;}
```

to your CSS and toggle this class on `<body>` using jQuery.

```
$('body').toggleClass('noScroll');
```

**b) the dirty way: apply CSS on the fly**

```
$('body').css({
  overflowY:'hidden'  // overflowY:'auto' to re-enable scroll.
})
```